# Ninja Forms + Conditional Logic

Tags: forms, conditional-statements, logic, ninja

What mean Contains, what can i do ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhR80.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It checks if the value in the field contains a substring.
Let's say you want to check if Email (field) CONTAINS "@yahoo.com" to do some conditional logic like showing the message "We don't allow Yahoo addresses!".